# When was the Principle of Explosion included into mathematical logic and by whom?

Tags: logic

The Principle of Explosion (PoE) seems particularly illogical. Philosophy authors rightly make a great deal of the PoE, while mathematical logic textbooks are usually rather coy and say very little about it, which suggests that the PoE is more of an embarrassment for ML.

So I wonder: When, why and by whom was it declared a "principle" of mathematical logic?

Please, stick to historical facts.

Thanks for scholarly links.

---

I use the expression "*mathematical logic textbooks*" and not "*classical logic textbooks*", because it is a fact of life that there are plenty of ***mathematical*** logic textbooks, while I am not aware of even one ***classical*** logic textbook (you can check on your preferred search engine if you don't believe me).

Still, both expressions are spurious. Logic is a cognitive capacity of human beings, and therefore clearly not some segment of any formal discipline, like mathematics; and the only formal logic we know of which can properly be called *classical* is that of Aristotle, and since what mathematicians call "Classical Logic" is contradictory to it, it can only be improperly called *classical*.

Comment: At least since [13th century](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)

Comment: This question seems to be more about pushing a personal philosophy in a condescending way, not a sincere request for historical information (information that the poster could probably acquire easily by doing some fairly cursory Google searches). Moreover, per the comments to Bumble's answer, it seems as if the poster thinks the question can be settled purely by adopting specific definitions, which makes answering even more pointless (of course, if we define a concept of exclusive negation, then the LNC for that kind of negation trivially follows; but what about nontrivial negation?).

Comment: @KristianBerry "*what about nontrivial negation?*" Whatever they are, non-trivial negations either are negations and then there is no logical difference, or they are not, and then they are not relevant to the logic of contradictions.  A contradiction is the conjunction of two terms, one the negation of the other. If we don't equivocate, a contradiction is false and then there is no logical possibility that it be true.

Comment: I think it's that classical logical is the most productive logic for mathematics, and CL includes the PoE. Something from Thinking About Mathematics may help "The first half of this century saw an intensive study of the role of classical logic...in the central fields of mathematics...In short, the principles in question [from classical logic mostly] were...accepted...because they are needed for the smooth practice of mathematics. In a sense, mathematicians could not help using these principles [from classical logic], and with hindsight we see how impoverished mathematics would be without them"

Comment: @JKusin "*mathematicians could not help using these principles*" They could. Just not smart enough. Humans survived more than 300,000 years without the PoE. Mathematicians are not smarter than natural selection. - 2. "*[from classical logic]*" The PoE is not classical logic. Aristotle is, and he took down the notion that you could derive anything logically from a contradiction. - 3. "*and with hindsight we see how impoverished mathematics would be without them*" Your hindsight seems to have a blind spot. The PoE is one of the reasons that mathematicians are now in a state of logical confusion.

Comment: Modern logicians and mathematicians are free to believe in the LNC for reasons besides the explosion argument, and many continue to do so, and the successful careers of relevant logicians are stark evidence that people can deny the explosion argument without tarnishing their academic reputation. And hardly any mathematics whatsoever depends on the minutiae of how individual mathematicians justify the LNC to themselves. I can understand doubting the explosion argument for technical reasons, but we're just committing Sayre's crime if we say that some wrong minor logical detail is that important.

Comment: I mean, maybe there's even a way to get at a deeper possible problem with the explosion argument, *without* pulling an Ayn Rand and proclaiming the fall of civilization because of that argument. How about, "Are intuitions about exclusion/cancellation stronger than the explosion argument, as justifiers for the LNC?" or, "Why did the logic community supplement the LNC with the explosion argument? Who was disputing the sufficiency of Aristotle's argument?" Then we don't have to accuse the community of insanity/stupidity (I mean I accept both Aristotle's *and* the explosion arguments, after all).

Comment: @KristianBerry "*some wrong minor logical detail is that important*" It is far from being a detail. It is the absurd consequence of an absurd theory, and this is Modus Tollens. The PoE in itself doesn't matter, but it is the absurd logical consequence of some assumptions, and as such it tells us that the assumptions are false. These assumptions are those of mathematical logic. I fail to see how that could be a "*minor detail*".

Comment: @KristianBerry "Are intuitions about exclusion/cancellation stronger than the explosion argument, as justifiers for the LNC?" There is no contest because there is just no ***logical*** "explosion argument".

Comment: @KristianBerry "*Then we don't have to accuse the community of insanity/stupidity*" I didn't. I said that the PoE is absurd, and I said that because this is true, not to insult anyone. If you can't face the real world, seek refuge in some alternative dimension.

Comment: @Speakpigeon you said there are textbooks that are "coy" about the topic because the PoE is an "embarrassment" to ML. I can see that the ref. to embarrassment is not about people directly, it's more like the phrase "embarrassment of riches," but the coyness has to be more personalized, and anyway your insistence that it is "obvious" that *your* definition of negation is the "ordinary" one and that the rest of us are equivocating for the sake of absurdity, is hard to take as anything other than an insult. Perhaps you have a different social sense than us and don't see how antisocial that seems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147302/discussion-between-kristian-berry-and-speakpigeon).

Answer (score 6):

The distinction between mathematical logic and the logic used by philosophers is spurious. Mathematical logic is not a specific kind of logic, but a general term for logic done using symbols with mathematical rigour. Most mathematicians use classical logic, and most philosophers who use logic also use classical logic, so the difference is not that great.

As to who first came up with the principle of explosion, it seems to be a whole bunch of people in the 12th century. Conifold gives a short history in his [answer to this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11736/how-did-the-principle-of-explosion-come-up-and-was-developed-historically). I've included a few references below.

The principle of explosion can be proved quite straightforwardly using fairly innocuous rules. One way uses disjunctive addition and disjunctive syllogism. Another uses conjunctive simplification and contraposition. Explosion is baked into classical logic and cannot be removed from it without turning it into a different logic. There are many logics that do not have explosion; they are called *paraconsistent* logics. These include minimal logic, the logic of paradox and the whole family of relevance logics.

Explosion is not an embarrassment to logic. It can be understood as one reason why the law of non-contradiction holds. No contradiction can be true because if it were, explosion and triviality would follow. By contrast, dialetheists are compelled to abandon explosion precisely because they hold that some contradictions are true. Explosion is useful in mathematics because it can be used to prove that a theory is consistent. An inconsistent theory entails a contradiction and by explosion proves anything whatsoever. So by contraposition, if there is even one formula that can be shown not to be provable by a theory, then the theory is consistent. This was used by Gentzen to prove the consistency of arithmetic.

- Martin, Christopher, J. (1986) "William's Machine" Journal of Philosophy, Vol. 83, No. 10, pp. 564-572.
- Ashe, L. (2020) "How to read both: The logic of true contradictions in Chaucer’s World" Studies in the Age of Chaucer, Vol. 42, pp. 111-146.
- Dutilh Novaes, Catarina and Stephen Read (eds.), (2016) *The Cambridge Companion to Medieval Logic*.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147286/discussion-on-answer-by-bumble-when-was-the-principle-of-explosion-included-into); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Whether there is only one concept of "purely logical" negation, which is then supposed to be exclusive or cancellative, is a point of contention nowadays. [To answer your historical question](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/#ArguExpl):

[image]

The two subsequent sections of that same article go over the belief that negation, when it is a purely logical function, is either exclusive or cancellative. Somewhat in defense of your proposal, in your comments, that negation "just is" LNC-obedient, there is mention made of Quine's "change the logic, change the subject" dictum: however else we use the word "not," one of its uses is to express or refer to cases of exclusion and cancellation, so a logic built on that usage is LNC-obedient by the by, "and we are done."

This sentiment is rather analogous to what is elsewhere known as [Suszko's thesis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-values/#SuszThesAntiDesiValu):

> In the 1970’s Roman Suszko (1977: 377) declared many-valued logic to be “a magnificent conceptual deceit”. Suszko actually claimed that “there are but two logical values, true and false” (Caleiro *et al.* 2005: 169), a statement now called Suszko’s Thesis. For Suszko, the set of truth values assumed in a logical matrix for a many-valued logic is a set of “admissible referents” (called “algebraic values”) of formulas but not a set of logical values. Whereas the algebraic values are elements of an algebraic structure and referents of formulas, the logical value *true* is used to define valid consequence: If every premise is true, then so is (at least one of) the conclusion(s). The other logical value, *false*, is preserved in the opposite direction: If the (every) conclusion is false, then so is at least one of the premises. The logical values are thus represented by a bi-partition of the set of algebraic values into a set of designated values (truth) and its complement (falsity).

Now, one might, by stipulative *fiat*, say that the word "logic" has one and only one legitimate use. If one thought oneself to have conceptually analyzed the word "logic" so successfully, to the demerit of any doubters and dissenters, I would be amazed (amazed that someone would be so arrogant, that is). For things do not appear to be so easy at all: even if negation as a whole is stipulatively exclusive/cancellative, we still seem to be able to think through a notion of [demi-negation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/connectives-logic/#NegIteExa3), with strong affinities with the notion of √-1, which is itself something people have inveighed against down to the present day "because by definition, multiplying two negatives or two positives makes a positive" (even though, it should be obvious, everyone who faithfully uses imaginary numbers has defined negative multiplication in such a way as allows their equations to go through; and so why would we privilege the definition favored by opponents of imaginary numbers?).

Or are intuitionist logicians using an "illegitimate" concept of negation, one which does not unequivocally support double-negation reduction, or exclusive disjunction? If their argument schemes yield *fewer* provable negations than Aristotle or Frege might believe in, then by the thesis of pure logicality as topic-neutrality or permutation-invariance, one might find reason to think that the weaker concept of negation/definition of the word "negation" used by intuitionists is even more abstract and generalized than the scholastic or modern definition, which would favor treating intuitionistic negation as the most truly, purely logical one, would it not? Again, is it in accordance with the *social normativity of language and public reason* to dogmatically proclaim that this or that definition (of "logic," "negation," or whatever else) is the only justified act of definition? Because it does not appear to be socially justified to use words in that way. While it might be justifiable to stick to specific definitions for the sake of specific arguments, especially to maintain clarity of representation for one's own sake, it is needlessly essentialistic to dictate to everyone, everywhere, for all time, that "logical negation" *must* be defined in one and only one way.

Or, then, if you really are asking about the philosophical history of logic, we must not forget [the history of regions outside of Europe, e.g. India](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/#DialEastAsiaPhil):

> In non-Western traditions, there are more overt examples of what appears to be dialetheic thought. In ancient Indian logic/metaphysics, there were standardly four possibilities to be considered on any statement at issue: that it is true (only), false (only), neither true nor false, or both true and false. Some logicians added a fifth possibility: none of these. Both positions were, arguably, called *catushkoti* (Priest 2002, ch.16; Deguchi et al 2008; Tillemans 2009.) The Jains went even further and advocated the possibility of contradictory values of the kind: true (only) and both true and false (see Smart 1964).

Would you say that ancient Hindu and Jain analysts were not using a family-resemblant cognate of "not"? Surely they were not using a very narrow definition for which the LNC trivially holds. But then is family resemblance a better model of conceptual analysis than the labyrinthine finesse of scholastics or Fregeans? At the very least, from the social-normativity standpoint, it is more illicit to talk in an imperiously condescending way to people using other definitions of "not," than it is for those other people to use their other definitions in the first place.

Comment: I like how you tie the issue of explosion and non-contradiction back to a theory of negation. I can see how a non-classical account of negation would permit a non-explosive and possibly even a dialethic logic. I take your basic point to be that no individual is in a position to dictate the definition of 'not', 'true', 'false', or 'logic'. One may adopt a definition and see where it leads, and some definitions may prove more popular than others. But at the end of the day, understanding these terms is a knotty and 'not'-y problem.

Comment: BTW, I've not come across that passage from Suszko before, but based just on what you quote, it seems to me he is mistaken. A key insight of Boolean logic is that true and false are referential values. They are themselves what Suszko calls admissible referents and are not unique. Classical valid consequence occurs when the designated value 'true' is preserved. With many-valued logics, other values are preserved. Furthermore, not all logics can be understood in terms of preservation, even of truth preservation, because some substructural logics lack transitivity or reflexivity of consequence.

Comment: @Bumble I was first turned on to the question of justifying the rules for the connectives in some non-definitional way by McGee's reflections on *modus ponens*. Beforehand, I had thought it "obvious" that the word "if" is such as is expressed by the affirming and denying modes. I never actually got much of a handle on McGee's objection, but then also given how Kant and Rawls are leery about conceptual analysis, I ended up inclined to use definitional arguments sparingly and hesitantly.

Comment: FWIW, I actually like the explosion argument on a sort of aesthetic level. It's the kind of subtle, but not overly convoluted, thinking that seems to have been profitable time and again in mathematics and physics, and due to my sympathy for coherentism, I'd prefer to support the LNC not *only* by appeal to some intuition about exclusion and cancellation, but by something more interesting, and the explosion argument is very interesting to me.

Comment: @KristianBerry Whatever philosophers may mean by "negation", either they mean "negation" in the ordinary sense, or they don't. If they mean "negation" in the ordinary sense, then there is no logical difference and then contradictions are just false and the PoE is just absurd; or they mean something else than negation in the ordinary sense, and then it is just equivocation and what they say is irrelevant to the logic of contradictions and therefore to the question of the PoE.

Comment: @KristianBerry "*one might, by stipulative fiat, say that the word "logic" has one and only one legitimate use*" People are absolutely free to use words any way they fancy, but if you use the word "logic" to mean something else than logic, then you don't speak English.

Comment: @Speakpigeon I really doubt that there's such a thing as "the one and only ordinary use of the word 'not'" (or "logic'). You sound like people who think that marriage has to be between one man and one woman "because that's how the word is defined." And since you are energizing your condescension and insulting remarks towards the logic/mathematics community on this basis, you seem to be violating the moral laws of public discourse to some extent.

Comment: @KristianBerry "*to the demerit of any doubters and dissenters, I would be amazed (amazed that someone would be so arrogant, that is).*" Oh, so now definitions are alright? I am in nearly complete agreement with the Aristotelian tradition, while Proponents of the PoE are not. They are the ones who pretend to be right against 2,600 years of the history of logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147296/discussion-between-kristian-berry-and-speakpigeon).

Comment: @KristianBerry  "*we still seem to be able to think through a notion of demi-negation*" And then this is not negation and therefore irrelevant to the question of the PoE.

Comment: @KristianBerry "*I really doubt that there's such a thing as "the one and only ordinary use of the word 'not'" (or "logic').*" ***First, I never said that, so your comment is just wilful misrepresentation.*** 2. Formal logic requires to eschew equivocation, the words "not" and "negation" have long been given one, unambiguous and very well-known definition, you cannot use the same words with a different meaning without equivocation, and equivocation makes for very bad logic. If you don't understand that, you don't understand formal logic, or any formal language for that matter.

Comment: @KristianBerry "*You sound like people who think*" Who cares who you think I sound like? Any rational argument do you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147303/discussion-between-kristian-berry-and-speakpigeon).